# Example from book failing to compile, converting ifstream into bool

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

I am a student of C++. I am working through the book, "Starting Out With C++ Early Objects (9th Edition). Example 27 from Chapter 6 (on Functions) reads data from a file but will not compile. Here is the full code:

```
// Program 6-27
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// Function prototype
bool readData(ifstream &someFile, string &city, double &rain);

int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    string city;
    double inchesOfRain;

    // Display table headings
    cout << "July Rainfall Totals for Selected Cities \n\n";
    cout << " City      Inches \n";
    cout << "_________________ \n";

    // Open the data file
    inputFile.open("rainfall.dat");
    if (inputFile.fail())
    cout << "Error opening data file.\n";
    else
    {
        // Call the readData function
        // Execute the loop as long as it found and read data
        while (readData(inputFile, city, inchesOfRain) == true)
        {
            cout << setw(11) << left << city;
            cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2)
                << inchesOfRain << endl;
        }
        inputFile.close();
    }
    return 0;
}

bool readData(ifstream &someFile, string &city, double &rain)
{
    bool foundData = someFile >> city >> rain;
    return foundData;
}
```

And here's the accompanying data for the data file Rainfall.dat:

```
Chicago 3.70
Tampa 6.49
Houston 3.80
```

The problem lies with this line in the "bool readData" function:

```
bool foundData = someFile >> city >> rain;
```

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017. "someFile" gets a red squiggly line and the dropdown displays the following error:

> no suitable conversion function from "`std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char>>`" to "`bool`" exists

I don't really understand the error message but have managed to get this program working with:

A simple cast:

```
bool readData(ifstream &someFile, string &city, double &rain)
{
    return static_cast<bool>(someFile >> city >> rain);
}
```

Or this as an alternative:

```
bool readData(ifstream &someFile, string &city, double &rain)
{
    if(someFile >> city >> rain)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

So, my real questions are:

- Are my solutions ok or is there a better way?
- why is an error being thrown at all on Educational material that you
  would imagine should have been thoroughly tested first. Or is this
  just Visual Studio (intelliSense) specific, but works just fine on
  other compilers?

Comment: Post error messages as verbatim text instead of images please!

Comment: Just use `return someFile >> city >> rain;` instead of this redundant `if() else` construct. There's no need for a `static_cast`.

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried return someFile >> city >> rain; first but still got the red squiggly. Only the cast removes it!

Comment: You might want to try [a more recent book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Off topic - but I find myself wondering why `readData` requires an `ifstream` instead of accepting any `istream` (which would be better if down the road you wanted to be able to read from `cin` or from an `istringstream` instead).  Then, as one of the answers hinted, I would tend to have it return `istream&` instead of the `bool`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd consider

- returning `std::ios&` to postpone the contextual conversion to `bool`

  ```
  std::ios& readData(std::ifstream &someFile, std::string &city, double &rain) {
      return someFile >> city >> rain;
  }
  ```

  The upshot is that you can simple use it like so down-the-road:

  ```
  if (readData(file, city, rain)) {
      // ...
  }
  ```

  The interface will compile with just including `#include <iosfwd>`

---

- manually triggering the contextual conversion:

  ```
  bool readData(std::ifstream &someFile, std::string &city, double &rain) {
      return bool{someFile >> city >> rain};
  }
  ```

Answer (score 6):

The stream has a member

```
explicit operator bool() const;
```

which makes it convertible to a `bool` value, but because the operator is `explicit` this only works in a context that *requires* a bool.

You have already discovered that this includes if-statements and explicit casts. It doesn't include other types of expressions, like assignments.

Originally (C++98) the operator wasn't `explicit` (because such things weren't invented yet) so the code example would probably have worked at the time. Seems like the book hasn't been updated in this part.

Comment: Doesn't really answer, why visual-studio-2017 intellisense rendering complains.

Comment: @user0042 Why not? The code is not valid C++11 or whatever the standard is that visual studio 2017 is trying to implement, so intellisense putting red squigglies under the code is what is supposed to happen.

Comment: Yep  that was my question 2. Did the author use an alternative non complaining compiler?

Comment: @nwp Doesn't the return type _require a `bool`_?

Comment: @Bo Yes, I also thought so. The intellisense parser doesn't follow the currently implemented standards. Often seen that with VS.

Comment: @user0042 It does, but apparently [it is still considered an implicit conversion](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8d2231e53db2037).

Comment: Everyone. FYI. This book is apparently bang up to date published 2017 and is supposed to be C++11 compliant.

Comment: @Webbmaster1 Well, [all the](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/557a60ed2e3f87bb) major [compilers](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8d2231e53db2037) disagree [with the](http://rextester.com/FZA94572) book. You could search for an errata for that book.

Comment: @Webbmaster1 - There are bugs in books as well. Not just in programs.

Answer (score 3):

The `operator bool` for streams is declared in the base class `basic_ios` the following way

```
explicit operator bool() const;
^^^^^^^^
```

So there is no implicit conversion from the `std::basic_ifstream` to the type `bool`.

This solution

```
bool readData(ifstream &someFile, string &city, double &rain)
{
    return static_cast<bool>(someFile >> city >> rain);
}
```

looks good.

You can also use a trick with the logical negation operator the following way

```
bool readData(ifstream &someFile, string &city, double &rain)
{
    return !!(someFile >> city >> rain);
}
```

because according to the C++ Standard (5.3.1 Unary operators)

> 9 The operand of the logical negation operator ! is **contextually
>   converted to bool** (Clause 4); its value is true if the converted
>   operand is false and false otherwise. The type of the result is bool.

Though in my opinion the first function implementation is more readable.

Comment: MSVC doesn't even support standards previous to C++14 any more, so one might just as well make good use of C++14 features. So what about changing the return type specificer of ``readData`` to ``decltype(auto)``? (The downside is of course that such a function cannot be forward-declared, so it needs to be moved up. Also the ``== true`` must be removed.)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose they don't cover it until later in the book, but I'd approach this somewhat differently. I'd start by defining a struct to hold the name and rainfall for a city together:

```
struct precipitation { 
    std::string location;
    double amount;
};
```

Then I'd define an overload of `operator>>` to extract an object of that type from a stream:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, precipitation &p) { 
     return is >> p.location >> p.amount;
}
```

This is pretty much the standard form for stream extractors--take reference to a stream and a reference to an object of the type being extracted, and return the stream (again, by reference).

This lets you read fairly cleanly:

```
precipitation precip;

std::ifstream in("rainfall.dat");

while (in >> precip)
    std::cout << "City: " << precip.location << ", amount: " << precip.amount << "\n";
```

In case you're wondering how that works: a stream object supports conversion to Boolean, which produces `true` when reading from the stream has succeeded, and `false` when it fails, so this reads from the stream until reading fails, then it stops.

This is also the form expected by stream iterators, so it lets you use them as well. For example, to read the entire contents of the file into a vector, you'd do something like this:

```
std::vector<precipitation> data { std::istream_iterator<precipitation>(in),{}};
```

Comment: You magically read my mind. I had the word `precipation` in a type in my answer at first! We must have been conjoined twins, separated at birth. Or something. (I removed it because it didn't feel essential to the question. Still +1 for going the educational mile!)